# Matplotlib : display several labels on a single line

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, legend

I've got a DF, like this one :

```
DF=pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"date":["2019-01-01","2019-01-02","2019-01-03","2019-01-04","2019-01-05","2019-01-06","2019-01-07","2019-01-08","2019-01-09","2019-01-10"],
                           "temperature":[9,7,5,14,17,18,16,13.5,19,21],
                           "shorter_opinion":["bad & very bad","bad & very bad","bad & very bad","not good not bad","good & very good", "good & very good", "good & very good","not good not bad","not good not bad","bad & very bad"]})
```

In order to visualize this with one color for each DF["shorter_opinion"] value, I crated a dict, and display like this :

```
colors={"good & very good":"green","not good not bad":"yellow","bad & very bad":"red"}

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x = DF["date"], y = DF["temperature"], c=DF["shorter_opinion"].map(colors))
plt.xticks(DF["date"][::3])
plt.legend(loc="upper right")
plt.show()
```

I tried to display this singles states in the legends, with Serie.Unique()

```
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x = DF["date"], y = DF["temperature"], c=DF["shorter_opinion"].map(colors), label=DF["shorter_opinion"].unique())
plt.xticks(DF["date"][::3])
plt.legend(loc="upper right")
plt.show()
```

But got this picture

[image]

How can I modify this code to have each value beside the right color ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution could be to use patches, like this :

```
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x = DF["date"], y = DF["temperature"], c=DF["shorter_opinion"].map(colors), label=DF["shorter_opinion"].unique())
plt.xticks(DF["date"][::3])
patches = [ plt.plot([],[], marker="o", ms=10, ls="", mec=None, color=colors[i], 
            label=i)[0]  for i in colors.keys() ]
plt.legend(colors.keys())
plt.show()
```